# Using Meteor within Phonegap Twitter auth fails to authenticate the user

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, meteor, twitter-oauth

I'm using this plugin:

https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-phonegap-oauth

And here's where I'm at in solving this:
https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-phonegap-oauth/issues/1#issuecomment-41835470

Basically, the redirects that happen in the phonegap inAppBrowser popup fail to pass the access_token and verifier to Meteor.